# How do I determine the last day of the previous month using PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I need to query a PostgreSQL database to determine records that fall within today's date and the last day of the previous month.  In other words, I'd like to retrieve everything that falls between December 31, 2011 and today. This query will be re-used each month, so next month, the query will be based upon the current date and January 31, 2012.

I've seen [this option](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Date_LastDay), but I'd prefer to avoid using a function (if possible).

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a function?

Comment: I would recommend using a function, so you have one point of update if at some point changes are required, however if you want to avoid it, simply replace $1 with date field

Comment: So do you want to **include** the last day of the last month?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yes, that's fine.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Both solutions **include** the last day of the previous month and also **include** all of "today".

#### For a `date` column:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  my_date BETWEEN date_trunc('month', now())::date - 1
               AND     now()::date
```

You can subtract plain integer values from a `date` (but not from a `timestamp`) to subtract days. This is the simplest and fastest way.

#### For a `timestamp` column:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  my_timestamp >= date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '1 day'
AND    my_timestamp <  date_trunc('day'  , now()) + interval '1 day'
```

I use the `<` operator for the second condition to get precise results (read: "before tomorrow").

I do not cast to `date` in the second query. Instead I add an `interval '1 day'`, to avoid casting back and forth.

Have a look at [date / time types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html)  and [functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE) in the manual.

Comment: This generates the following error: operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone - integer

Comment: @Huunze: should be fixed by now.

Comment: I think we're getting closer. This seems to be working, but it's excluding values with today's date.

Comment: Tried this for the 2nd portion of the BETWEEN and it worked: date_trunc('DAY', now())::date+1. Doesn't feel right, but it works. Suggestions?

Comment: @Huuuze: From your comments I deduce that your column (`my_date` in my example) is **not** actually a `date`, but a `timestamp`. You should have provided this information. I amended my answer with an additional solution for timestamps. Note, that the solution you describe in the comment would include "tomorrow, 00:00", which would be wrong.

Comment: How can I get the first day *date* of the previous month ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit: `date_trunc('month', now() - interval '1 month')::date`

Comment: @ArupRakshit: Use a *question* next time. Comments are not meant for new questions. You can always link to another answer for reference ...

Answer (score 6):

For getting **date** of previous/last month:

```
SELECT (date_trunc('month', now())::date - 1) as last_month_date
```

*Result: 2012-11-30*

For getting **number of days** of previous/last month:

```
SELECT DATE_PART('days', date_trunc('month', now())::date - 1) last_month_days
```

*Result: 30*

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE  date_field between (date_trunc('MONTH', now()) - INTERVAL '1 day')::date 
                      and now()::date 
       ...
```

Comment: it needs to be just `'-1 day'::interval` for the OP's actual requirement

Comment: @araqnid As you noted, the query above isn't working. How do I integrate your suggestion into the suggested query?

Comment: @MarkBannister I have a record that falls between December 31, 2011 and today, but your query does not return it.  If I remove your suggestion from my query and replace it with "2011-12-31", the expected result occurs.

Comment: @Huuze: Try the amended formula.

Comment: @MarkBannister I must be doing something wrong. Here's my/your WHERE clause:  my_date >= (date_trunc('MONTH', my_date) - INTERVAL '1 day')::date and my_date <= now(). This returns results that are dated December 20. Thoughts?

Comment: @huuuze: use `date_trunc('MONTH', now()) - INTERVAL '1 day')` to get the end-of-month before *now* rather than `my_date`

Comment: @Huuuze: Yes, I had written it wrong. If this still doesn't work, I'm going to delete this answer and give up. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select current_date - cast((date_part('day', current_date) + 1) as int)
```

Answer (score 0):

take from http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Date_LastDay, and modified to return just the days in a month

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calc_days_in_month(date)
    RETURNS double precision AS
    $$
      SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM (date_trunc('MONTH', $1) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1         day')::date);
    $$ LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE STRICT;


    select calc_days_in_month('1999-05-01')
```

returns 31

Answer (score 0):

**[Reference is taken from this blog:](http://www.dbrnd.com/2017/01/postgresql-how-to-find-last-day-of-the-month/)**

**You can use below function:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_GetLastDayOfMonth(DATE)
RETURNS DATE AS
$$
    SELECT (date_trunc('MONTH', $1) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::DATE;
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql' 
IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

**Sample executions:**

```
SELECT *FROM fn_GetLastDayOfMonth(NOW()::DATE);
```