# LAST_DAY function in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is there any function(s) in postgres equivalent to Oracle function LAST_DAY().

I need to get last day in postgres (including month and year)

Comment: Here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944721/how-do-i-determine-the-last-day-of-the-previous-month-using-postgresql

Answer (score 39):

Well, In postgres, it seems there's no such function equivalent to `LAST_DAY()` available in oracle.

If you need to, you can have your own in the following ways as a

### Select Query

```
SELECT (date_trunc('MONTH', now()) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::date;
```

### plsql Function

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION last_day(date)
        RETURNS date AS
        $$
        SELECT (date_trunc('MONTH', $1) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::date;
        $$ LANGUAGE 'sql'
        IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Gopinagh..It's fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace funCtion last_day(fromdt anyelement)
returns date as
$BODY$
  SELECT (date_trunc('MONTH', cast(fromdt as date)) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::date;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
  ALTER FUNCTION last_day(anyelement)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: postgres does not have last_day function we need to create user defined function