# How to get the last day of month in postgres?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

How to find the last day os the month in postgres?
I have a date columns stored as numeric(18) in the format(YYYYMMDD)
I am trying it to make it date using

```
to_date("act_dt",'YYYYMMDD') AS "act date"
```

then find the last day of this date:
like this:

```
(select (date_trunc('MONTH',to_date("act_dt",'YYYYMMDD')) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::date)
```

but it gives me this error:

```
ERROR: Interval values with month or year parts are not supported
  Detail: 
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Interval values with month or year parts are not supported
  code:      8001
  context:   interval months: "1"
  query:     673376
  location:  cg_constmanager.cpp:145
  process:   padbmaster [pid=20937]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

Any help?

Postgres version:

`PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.874`

Comment: `to_date` converts only strings to dates. If your column contains Unix epoch values, you need to use `to_timestamp`: `to_timestamp(act_dt)::date`.

Comment: @AudriusKažukauskas :  
ERROR: function to_timestamp(numeric) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts. ?

Comment: `to_timestamp` expects double precision type, try casting your column to it: `to_timestamp(act_dt::float8)::date`. BTW, could you confirm that this column stores Unix epoch time values? If this is not the case, you should provide explanation in your question what exactly is it storing.

Comment: You can do your calculation by replacing your `INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day'` by `INTERVAL '1 MONTH' - interval '1 day'`

Comment: @AudriusKažukauskas : the column has values like this act_dt `20131014 20130614 20150124 20110128 20120825`

Comment: OK then, scrap everything I wrote, @Houari answer should work for you. Although I'd strongly recommend to store date values using date type (of course, if this is not some legacy system, where it's not up to you to decide column types).

Comment: SELECT (date_trunc('MONTH', Current_Date) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::DATE;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using Amazon AWS Redshift then you can use Redshift's `LAST_DAY` function. While Redshift is based on PostgreSQL, **the `LAST_DAY` function is not available in PostgreSQL**, for a solution for PostgreSQL [see @wspurgin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45740174/159145).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LAST_DAY.html

> ```
> LAST_DAY( { date | timestamp } )
> ```
>
> `LAST_DAY` returns the date of the last day of the month that contains date. The return type is always `DATE`, regardless of the data type of the date argument.

For example:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY( TO_DATE( act_date, 'YYYYMMDD' ) )
```

Comment: `ERROR: Interval values with month or year parts are not supported
  Detail: 
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Interval values with month or year parts are not supported
  code:      8001
  context:   interval months: "1"
  query:     674275` any help?

Comment: @HareRamaHareKrishna: what is your exact Postgres version? Please edit your question and add the output of `select version()` to your question.

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi It should work even for `numeric`, i don't see problem executing my answer even on 'Pre-histrical' version :s

Comment: `date columns stored as numeric(18) `

Comment: @Houari : When I use the same code as above I am not able to get it right it throws same error as I put in my question? thanks

Comment: @Houari maybe it's because this is Amazon Redshift, which is only based on Postgres 8.0.

Comment: Yes , and it change lot of things! You should put RedShift tag at first

Comment: And don't really know redShift, but try this: `select dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,1,date_trunc('month',to_date(to_char(act_dt,'99999999'), 'YYYYMMDD'))))`

Comment: @Houari : I tried it, but it show like this:act_dt 
`20111024 2011-11-30 00:00:00
20150127 2019-02-28 00:00:00
20150127 2019-02-28 00:00:00
20150127 2019-02-28 00:00:00
20150127 2019-02-28 00:00:00`   for 20150127 it gives 2019-02-28?

Comment: [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LAST_DAY.html) they are talking about `last_day` function, could you please try: `select last_day(to_date(to_char(act_dt,'999999‌​99'), 'YYYYMMDD'))` ?

Comment: @Houari : Thanks a ton This works : `select last_day(to_date(act_date,'YYYYMMDD'))`

Comment: `last_day()` is not a Postgres function. Although it _would_ work for the original poster (who does say at the end they're running `PostgreSQL 8.0.2` on AWS Redshift) it isn't actually an answer to the question they asked, specifically "How to get the last day of month in postgres?"

Comment: @Molomby Thank you. This is extremely confusing, especially with a contradictory answer like https://stackoverflow.com/a/14229242/2537548.

Answer (score 138):

For anybody coming to this question looking for the *Postgres* way to do this (not using Redshift), here's how you'd do it:

```
SELECT (date_trunc('month', '2017-01-05'::date) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day')::date
AS end_of_month;
```

Replacing the `'2017-01-05'` with whatever date you want to use. You can make this into a function like this:

```
create function end_of_month(date)
returns date as
$$
select (date_trunc('month', $1) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day')::date;
$$ language 'sql'
immutable strict;
```

#### EDIT Postgres 11+

Pulling this out of the comments from [@Gabriel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186014/how-to-get-the-last-day-of-month-in-postgres/45740174#comment115114539_45740174), you can now combine interval expressions in one `interval` (which makes things a little shorter):

```sql
select (date_trunc('month', now()) + interval '1 month - 1 day')::date as end_of_month;

-- +--------------+
-- | end_of_month |
-- +--------------+
-- | 2021-11-30   |
-- +--------------+
-- (1 row)
```

Comment: last_day is simplier and also probabily faster than your solution. Why someone should use all this stuff instead of a simple last_day ?

Comment: @giò because last_day is a redshift function. As I said in my answer this is how you do the same thing with PostgreSQL only. For those who come to this question and aren’t using redshift, this is how they can achieve the same thing as the last_day function. As to whether it’s faster/slower, who can say? Feel free to test them yourself and you can inform us all.

Comment: ohh i didn't know that postgres didn't have last_day function, what a shame

Comment: You can also do the interval math within a single interval, at least in PG11+ 
select date_trunc('month', now()) + interval '1 month -1 day'

Answer (score 8):

```
date_trunc('month',current_date) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day'
```

Truncating any date or timestamp to the month level will give you the first of the month containing that date.  Adding a month gives you the first of the following month.  Then, removing a day will give you the date of the last day of the month of the provided date.

Comment: another alternative:  select   date_trunc('month', current_date ) - interval '1 day'

Answer (score 6):

Okay, so you've got a `numeric(18)` column containing numbers like `20150118`.  You can convert that to a date like:

```
to_date(your_date_column::text, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

From a date, you can grab [the last day of the month](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Date_LastDay) like:

```
(date_trunc('month', your_date_column) + 
    interval '1 month' - interval '1 day')::date;
```

Combined, you'd get:

```
select  (date_trunc('month', to_date(act_dt::text, 'YYYYMMDD')) + 
           interval '1 month' - interval '1 day')::date
from    YourTable;
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ec6a0/2/0)

Comment: Andomar: Now() is my `integer date`,need to make it date then use it in place of now().. something like this is not working `(select (date_trunc('MONTH',to_date("act_dt",'YYYYMMDD')) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::date) it gives me error as above
`

Comment: @HareRamaHareKrishna: that was obvious from your question, sorry. Updated the answer.

Comment: ERROR: function to_timestamp(numeric) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts. ?

Comment: For me it works with a numeric argument... which version of Postgres are you using?  Does `to_timestamp(act_dt::float)` work?  Where `::type` is a Postgres type cast.

Comment: hmm.. I use this to convert it to date `to_date("act_dt",'YYYYMMDD')`

Comment: If you already have a `date` object, there is no need to use `timestamp()` on it. Try the updated answer?

Comment: `date columns stored as numeric(18)`

Comment: Ok, was able to reproduce your problem. Updated answer works for me!

Answer (score 0):

For future searches, Redshift does not accept `INTERVAL '1 month'`. Instead use `dateadd(month, 1, date)` as documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEADD_function.html).

To get the end of the month use: `DATEADD(DAY, -1, (DATE_TRUNC('month', DATEADD(MONTH, 1, date))))`

Answer (score 0):

select to_char(date_trunc('month', now() + '01 Months'::interval) - '01 Days'::interval, 'YYYYmmDD'::text)::numeric as end_period_n

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
select date( date_trunc ('month', (current_date + INTERVAL '1 Month '))) -1 ;
```

hope this help full