# How do I round-up a date to the last day of the month in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a `date` column called `hire_date` in the following format `YYYY-MM-DD`. I want to truncate the date so that the last day of the month is shown. For example, a record with `2015-01-11` is shown as `2015-01-31`.

I know that I can use `DATE_TRUNC('month', hire_date)` to get a timestamp of the beginning of the month but what about the end of the month?

The answer selected here [How to get the last day of month in postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186014/how-to-get-the-last-day-of-month-in-postgres) states to use the `last_day()` function but I've tried `LAST_DAY(hire_date)` and I get an error saying `function last_day(date) does not exist`.

Is there an easier way than the following:

```
DATE_TRUNC('month', hire_date) + INTERVAL '1 month' - INTERVAL '1 day'
```

Comment: last_day is not a PG function. Instead you could convert your own solution into a function

Comment: In databases, date columns don't have "formats".

Comment: "I want to truncate the date so that the last day of the month is shown" - **that is not what "truncate" means**.

Comment: @Dai Do you have a solution besides the calculation at the bottom of my post?

Comment: No, and your question _is the same_ as the question you linked to - just use the non-Redshift-specific answer. Also, some general advice: when working with date-ranges it's far better to use **exclusive upper-bounds** than inclusive-upper-bounds, that way you can avoid your problem entirely.

Comment: @Dai No, because that's the same link I provided in my post.

Comment: The "does this answer your question" comment is automatically added by SO whenever users make a vote-to-close-because-duplicate.

Comment: @Dai Please don't mark my question as having been answered. My question is, "is there an easier way than the following." Surely Postgres has a function like EOMONTH() in MS SQL.

Comment: @IamWarmduscher That sub-question of yours ("is there an easier way...?") **is** answered by that question - and the answer is "no" - I suggest you **read all the answers** posted there. The best alternative is to write a scalar UDF - or even better: not using inclusive-upper-bounds for date-ranges.