# SQL query to find gaps within a column of dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with status and date for every day and I'm trying to find out when the statuses change and if there's gaps within each status change / how many days were of a certain status.

```
+------+----------------+--------+
| user | date           | status |
+----- +----------------+--------+
|    1 | 12/01/2017     | open   |
|    1 | 12/02/2017     | open   |
|    1 | 12/03/2017     | open   |
|    1 | 12/04/2017     | closed |
|    1 | 12/05/2017     | closed |
|    1 | 12/06/2017     | open   |
|    1 | 12/07/2017     | open   |
+------+----------------+--------+
```

Expected output:

```
+------+------------+----------------+-------- ----+------------+
| user | status     | days_in_status | min         | max        |
+----- +------------+----------------+-------------+------------+
|    1 | open       | 3              | 12/01/2017  | 12/03/2017 |
|    1 | closed     | 2              | 12/04/2017  | 12/05/2017 |
|    1 | open       | 2              | 12/06/2017  | 12/07/2017 |
+------+------ -----+----------------+-------------+-- ---------+
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  In this case, subtracting a sequential number from each day is probably the simplest solution for identifying the "islands":

```
select user, status, count(*) as num_days, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user, status order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by user, status, date - seqnum * interval '1 day'
```

Comment: This worked! Can you explain what the `GROUP BY date - seqnum * interval '1 day'` is doing? 
`

Comment: great answer , avoiding an extra window function! @ptlx24 it''s basically producing a date fro each batch of userid, status , and since second batch of userid =1 and status = open have a gap in the "date" due to "closed" status in middle, that statement produce different date than first batch of "open" status , so its acting like a separator that you can group by

Comment: wow thank you so much! this is helpful! :)

Comment: @ptlx24 . . . It is subtracting `seqnum` days from a date.  That is a constant value when adjacent rows have an incrementing number of days.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres you can subtract `integer` from `date` directly:

```sql
SELECT "user", status
     , count(*) AS days_in_status, min(date) AS min, max(date) AS max
FROM  (
   SELECT "user", status, date
        , date - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY "user", status ORDER BY date)::int AS grp_date
   FROM   tbl
   ) t
GROUP BY "user", status, grp_date
ORDER BY "user", min;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c2b7ca46b78d0d6445d252a56f6faedb)*

See:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35389/3684)
- [How do I determine the last day of the previous month using PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944721/how-do-i-determine-the-last-day-of-the-previous-month-using-postgresql/8945281#8945281)

Aside: `user` is a [reserved word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944721/how-do-i-determine-the-last-day-of-the-previous-month-using-postgresql/8945281#8945281), you would avoid it as actual column name.

Answer (score 0):

### SQL query to find the width of date gaps within dates

Fully contained example borrowing from Gordon's answer above that shows island widths as well as island gaps, copy and paste into postgresql and run it.

```
drop table if exists foobar; 
CREATE TABLE foobar( tick text, date_val date ); 

insert into foobar values('XYZ', '2021-01-03');  --island 1 has width 2
insert into foobar values('XYZ', '2021-01-04');  --island 1
insert into foobar values('XYZ', '2021-05-09');  --island 2 has width 3
insert into foobar values('XYZ', '2021-05-10');  --island 2 
insert into foobar values('XYZ', '2021-05-11');  --island 2
insert into foobar values('XYZ', '2021-07-07');  --island 3 has width 4
insert into foobar values('XYZ', '2021-07-08');  --island 3
insert into foobar values('XYZ', '2021-07-09');  --island 3
insert into foobar values('XYZ', '2021-07-10');  --island 3 
insert into foobar values('XYZ', '2022-10-10');  --island 4 has width 1

select tick, island_width, min_val, max_val, 
       min_val - lag(max_val) over (order by max_val) as gap_width from  
( 
  select tick, count(*) as island_width, 
         min(date_val) min_val, max(date_val) max_val 
  from ( 
    select t.*, 
    row_number() over ( partition by tick order by date_val ) as seqnum 
    from foobar t where tick = 'XYZ' 
    ) t 
  group by tick, date_val - seqnum * interval '1 day' 
) t2 order by max_val desc
```

**Prints:**

```
┌──────┬──────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬───────────┐ 
│ tick │ island_width │  min_val   │  max_val   │ gap_width │ 
├──────┼──────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼───────────┤ 
│ XYZ  │            1 │ 2022-10-10 │ 2022-10-10 │       457 │ 
│ XYZ  │            4 │ 2021-07-07 │ 2021-07-10 │        57 │ 
│ XYZ  │            3 │ 2021-05-09 │ 2021-05-11 │       125 │ 
│ XYZ  │            2 │ 2021-01-03 │ 2021-01-04 │         ¤ │ 
└──────┴──────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴───────────┘
```

**Details:** In this data there are 4 islands.  There are 3 gaps between the 4 islands.  The last island has a gap. The first island has a null gap.

The SQL finds the days between every `min_date` and `max_date` by subtracting a day and decrementing rownumber until all dates are accounted for.  `partition` somehow groups the islands by date and a 2 day moving window using `over` and `lag` with default lookbehind 1. Black Box Demon magic aside it goes fast enough and all unit tests pass.

[image]

With help from walkthrough here: https://bertwagner.com/posts/gaps-and-islands

### Same as above but make gaps count hours rather than days:

```
drop table if exists foobar; 
CREATE TABLE foobar( tick text, date_val timestamp); 
insert into foobar values('XYZ', '2021-01-03 12:00:00');  
insert into foobar values('XYZ', '2021-01-03 11:00:00'); 
insert into foobar values('XYZ', '2021-01-03 10:00:00'); 
insert into foobar values('XYZ', '2021-01-03 08:00:00');  --2 hr gap
insert into foobar values('XYZ', '2021-01-03 07:00:00'); 
insert into foobar values('XYZ', '2021-01-03 06:00:00'); 
insert into foobar values('XYZ', '2021-01-03 03:00:00');  --3 hr gap
select tick, island_width, min_val, max_val, 
       min_val - lag(max_val) over (order by max_val) as gap_width from 
( 
  select tick, count(*) as island_width, 
         min(date_val) min_val, max(date_val) max_val 
  from ( 
    select t.*, 
    row_number() over ( partition by tick order by date_val ) as seqnum 
    from foobar t where tick = 'XYZ' 
    ) t 
  group by tick, date_val - seqnum * interval '1 hour' 
) t2 order by max_val desc
```

Prints:

```
┌──────┬──────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬───────────┐
│ tick │ island_width │       min_val       │       max_val       │ gap_width │
├──────┼──────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼───────────┤
│ XYZ  │            3 │ 2021-01-03 10:00:00 │ 2021-01-03 12:00:00 │ 02:00:00  │
│ XYZ  │            3 │ 2021-01-03 06:00:00 │ 2021-01-03 08:00:00 │ 03:00:00  │
│ XYZ  │            1 │ 2021-01-03 03:00:00 │ 2021-01-03 03:00:00 │ ¤         │
└──────┴──────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────────┘
```