# Get combined intervals for overlapping sessions

Tags: sql, postgresql, intervals, gaps-and-islands

I want to calculate session intervals for multiple, possibly overlapping sessions per agent. I have a log table like this in a PostgreSQL database:

```
id  dt                  session_id  agent_id state
7   2024-01-25 22:26:57 4           3148    0
7   2024-01-25 22:24:57 4           3148    1
6   2024-01-25 22:23:57 2           3148    0
5   2024-01-25 15:53:30 1           3148    0
4   2024-01-25 15:53:30 3           3148    0
3   2024-01-25 13:53:02 3           3148    1
2   2024-01-25 12:43:10 2           3148    1
1   2024-01-25 12:30:02 1           3148    1
```

`state = 1` indicates the start of a session, `state = 0` its end.
For single sessions I use the `lag()` function:

```
select agent_id, status, dt, lag(dt) over (partition by (agent_id) order by dt) as pre_status_dt  from 
(
    select *, 
      lag(status) over (partition by (agent_id) order by dt) as pre_status 
    from (
        select cs.dt, cs.user_id as agent_id, cs.status
        from "channel_subscribe" cs 
        where cs.channel = 14
    ) as t1
    where t1.dt >= '2024-01-01'
) as t2
where t2.status != t2.pre_status
order by dt asc
```

But that does not work for overlapping sessions.

I would like to get this result:

```
agent_id  start_dt             end_dt
3148      2024-01-25 12:30:02  2024-01-25 22:23:57
3148      2024-01-25 22:24:57  2024-01-25 22:26:57
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly how your expected result follows from the sample. For sessions 1 and 4 it seems like that makes some sense. Start is the record where state is 1, end is the record where state is 0. What about the others, could you describe this logic for an interval a bit more? Your query is just getting records where the status changed and the associated timestamp of the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample shows nested sessions: Additional sessions start and end within the first open session of the same agent. Alternatively, sessions might be chained: next session starts within the first session, but ends later.

The following solutions cover both cases: A combined session starts with the first open session, and ends once all open sessions have been closed.

Each assumes **consistent data**: Every session that gets closed has been opened before (or at the same time, but with am earlier `id`). Unfinished sessions are reported as such (with null for `end_dt`). If your data is not as reliable, you need to define what can go wrong, and handle cases accordingly.

#### Pure SQL

```sql
SELECT agent_id
     , min(dt) AS start_dt
     , max(dt) FILTER (WHERE sum_state = 0) AS end_dt  -- !
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE sum_state = 0)
          OVER (PARTITION BY agent_id ORDER BY dt DESC, id DESC) AS island
   FROM  (
      SELECT *
           , sum(CASE state WHEN 0 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END)
             OVER (PARTITION BY agent_id ORDER BY dt, id) sum_state
      FROM   channel_subscribe
      ) sub1
   ) sub2
GROUP  BY agent_id, island
ORDER  BY agent_id, island DESC;
```

The query in **`sub1`** adds a running count per agent as `sum_state`. A combined session ends when `sum_state` goes back to *0*.

Subquery **`sub2`** forms groups (`island`) by counting "0"-events per agent. Note the descending sort (`DESC`) to include each "0"-event in its group.

The **outer query** reports data as requested for every combined session. The added `FILTER (WHERE sum_state = 0)` makes sure that unfinished sessions are reported as such.

#### Procedural solution

Once we need multiple subquery levels (with changing sort order), it's probably faster to use a (combined) procedural solution like this PL/pgSQL function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_combined_sessions()
  RETURNS TABLE (agent_id int, start_dt timestamp, end_dt timestamp)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   r            record;
   _new_session bool;
   _agent_id    int;
BEGIN
   FOR r IN
      SELECT c.agent_id, c.dt
           , sum(CASE c.state WHEN 0 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END)
             OVER (PARTITION BY c.agent_id ORDER BY c.dt, c.id) AS sum_state
      FROM   channel_subscribe c
      ORDER  BY c.agent_id,  c.dt, c.id
   LOOP
      IF agent_id = r.agent_id THEN  -- same agent
         IF _new_session = true THEN
            start_dt     := r.dt;
            _new_session := false;
         END IF;
      ELSE                           -- new agent
         -- return open session?
         IF _new_session = false THEN
            end_dt := null;
            RETURN NEXT;
         END IF;
         agent_id     := r.agent_id;
         start_dt     := r.dt;
         _new_session := false;
      END IF;
      
      IF r.sum_state = 0 THEN
         end_dt := r.dt;
         RETURN NEXT;
         _new_session := true;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   -- return last open session?
   IF _new_session = false THEN
      end_dt := null;
      RETURN NEXT;
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_combined_sessions();
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nbPRUfSt)

---

Related:

- [Jump SQL gap over specific condition & proper lead() usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480818/jump-sql-gap-over-specific-condition-proper-lead-usage/12502786#12502786)
- [Get most recent streak (consecutive days) for given event and time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75816823/get-most-recent-streak-consecutive-days-for-given-event-and-time-zone/75818290#75818290)